# How to copy all constrains and data form one schema to another in oracle

Tags: oracle, constraints, unique-key

I am using Toad for oracle 12c. I need to copy a table and data (40M) from one shcema to another (prod to test). However there is an unique key(not the PK for this table) called record_Id col which  has something data like this 3.000*******19E15. About 2M rows has same numbers(I believe its because very large number) which are unique in prod. When I try to copy it violets the unique key of that col.  I am using toad "export data to another schema" function to copy the data.

when I execute query in prod

```
 select count(*) from table_name
```

OR

```
select count(distinct(record_id) from table_name
```

Both query gives the exact same numbers of data.

I don't have DBA permission. How do I copy all data without violating unique key of the table.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I didnt understand why in production are unique but when exporting them are being the same. however you can remove this unique key in test, then add the data then you add unique key with cascade option. would that be good to you ?

Comment: In my opinion, the correct way to do that is to use data pump.

Comment: Does the table in the test schema already contain data?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UPSERT` for decisional INSERT or UPDATE or you may write small procedure for this.

you may consider to use  `NOT EXISTS`, but your data is big and it might not be resource efficient.

```
insert into prod_tab 
  select * from other_tab t1 where NOT exists (
     select 1 from prod_tab t2 where t1.id = t2.id
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle you can use a [`MERGE` query](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm) for that.

The following query proceeds as follows for each data row :

- if the source `record_id` does not yet exist in the target table, a new record is *inserted*
- else, the existing record is *updated* with source values

For the sake of the example, I assumed that there are two other columns in the table : `column1` and `column2`.

```
MERGE INTO target_table t1
USING (SELECT * from source_table t2)
ON (t1.record_id = t2.record_id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
    t1.column1 = t2.column1,
    t1.column2 = t2.column2
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT
    (record_id, column1, column2) VALUES (t2.record_id, t2.column1, t2.column2)
```